# Who wrote the beginning of Alan Wake?

Tags: alan-wake

I am currently replaying Alan Wake, and the way I understand it, the basic premise is:

> The Dark Presence is malevolent, but needs someone creative, like Thomas Zane or Alan Wake, to spread and actually do any harm. This is why the Dark Presence is interested in both of them: It's their creativity that warps reality, the Dark Presence can't do it alone. All it can do is fill in any Plot Holes in the worst possible way to influence the stories Zane or Wake create.

However, what I don't understand is:

> How was the Dark Presence able to create Diver's Island in the beginning, or distract Stucky and hand over the keys to the island as Barbara Jagger? I think it wasn't written by Zane who wrote himself almost out of existence, nor was it written at that point by Wake as he was at that point not yet under the influence of the Dark Presence and would not ever have landed under said influence if Barbara Jagger/Diver's Island hadn't been there.

Comment: +1 already for the mere fact that you are asking a question about the plot of "Alan Wake", IMHO a wonderful game whose plot absolutely deserves being followed, rather than just being considered a backdrop for an FPS game.